# Update/reset state with existing one - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, state

I have quite an head scratcher here . I have some check boxes . After check box is selected you are abble to download a document based on the selected checkbox . After my download is completed i disable my checkbox , but still it is marked as checked . UI wise i inform the user that this section is downloaded . But if a user selects another checkbox from the same page the previous one is enabled again ( so it is not disabled anymore ) . My question is how can i update or reset my state in order to have all check boxes disabled and download only the documents that are selected at the moment and not the previous ones .

```
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { docList: {} }
```

after that this is my function to handle the checkboxes :

```
    handleCheckboxClick = (e) => {
let parsedVal = JSON.parse(e.target.value);
let newDocList = { ...this.state.docList };
if (e.target.checked) {
    newDocList[parsedVal.documentId] = parsedVal.documentNumber;
} else {
    delete newDocList[parsedVal.documentId];
}
this.setState({
    docList: newDocList,
}, () => {
    console.log(this.state.docList)
});
```

after that is my `axios.post` method :

```
    axios.post(SERVER_URL + '/api/user/bills/zip', postZipData, axiosZipConfig)

        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                downloadedIDS: response.data.downloadedIds,
                docList: this.state.docList
            })    e.preventDefault();
```

and the render :

```
const { downloadedIDS, docList } = this.state;

render: rowData =>
              <Checkbox
              disabled={downloadedIDS && downloadedIDS.indexOf(rowData.documentId) >= 0 ? true : false}
              color='default'
              value={JSON.stringify({ documentId: rowData.documentId, documentNumber: rowData.documentNumber })}
              onClick={this.handleCheckboxClick} />
```

The result is this : 
[image]

Any advice is welcome how should i treat my code .

Answer (score 0):

In this section...

```
.then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                downloadedIDS: response.data.downloadedIds,
                docList: this.state.docList
            })    e.preventDefault();
```

It seems you're overwriting `downloadedIds` with the IDs from the response that's just returned. If I understand correctly, it seems like you should append the IDs from the response to the existing state of `downloadedIds`.

Assuming `downloadedIds` is an array here is how you can achieve this using the [array spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
this.setState({
    downloadedIds: [
        ...this.state.downloadedIds,
        ...response.data.downloadedIds
    ]
})
```

There is no point in setting docList state to equal `this.state.docList` that will just set the state to equal the same thing, so it's not required.

Hope this helps, let me know if I can go into any more detail.